# Scaling vectors in illustrator causes artefacts

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

When i scale down a logo in an illustrator files ( i expanded all the effects and appearances) i get some weird artefacts, the curves get distorted. Is their any way around this ? Because exporting the logo and importing it as PNG seems a bit dumb for print.

[image: big logo- no issues (copy pasted from another illustrator document]

[image: Scaled down logo with distorted curves]

Comment: Found an answer here on stack ! http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20563/preventing-illustrator-cc-vector-objects-distorting-when-scaled

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer here on stack ! [Preventing Illustrator CC vector objects distorting when scaled](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20563/preventing-illustrator-cc-vector-objects-distorting-when-scaled)

Just selecting everything and unchecking Align to pixel grid (in the transform panel) worked very wel for me